# Basic C program has stopped working: just in time debugger

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, visual-studio-debugging

I am learning C at the moment and have copied the following from wibit.com:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int* n;
    *n = 20;
    printf("%i\n", *n);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using GCC and compiling and running in cmd prompt like so:

```
gcc prgrm.c -o prgrm.exe    #compiles without any errors
prgrm.exe
```

Then the error pops up saying prgrm.exe has stopped working. I click debug and get this:

[image: Debug Report]

All my programs have run before and I tested it with another few (just return 0; or printf(etc...) ) and they work!

Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int* n;
```

declares a pointer to `int`.  It has no address assigned so points to an arbitrary address in memory.  This address almost certainly won't be writable.  Even if it was writable, it isn't your memory so you don't know what the effects of writing it will be.

```
*n = 20;
```

tries to write to this unpredictable address.  This results in undefined behaviour.  Crashing is a valid (and useful) type of undefined behaviour.

To make your program work, you need to allocate storage for `n`.  You can do this on the stack

```
int n;
n = 20;
printf("%i\n", n);
```

or dynamically on the heap

```
int* n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
if (n == NULL) {
    printf("Error: out of memory\n");
    return -1;
}
*n = 20;
printf("%i\n", *n);
free(n);
```

Note that your compiler would have warned you about this use of an uninitialised variable if you enabled warnings for your build.  Add `-Wall` to your command line for gcc or `/W4` for MSVC to enable this.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer!